# SwiftUI can't save Photos on SiliconMac?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, apple-silicon

Here is the report about Trouble to save into Photo Library when running on Silicon Mac with SwiftUI iOS code as iPad-mode.
Is this a disability or am I making a mistake? Please tell me.

###### Environment of making App and excution

- Xcode 14.2
- MacOS Monterey 12.6.2, 12.6.3  on SiliconMac, iMac24

###### About troubled issue

My iOS App that was previously working well, some day returns an error on save to Photo Library, even though nothing has changed in the saving code.
And this problem only occurs on SiliconMac with iPad-mode. No problem with other iOS devices, iPhone, iPad.
’Some day’ mean i don’t know why, may be updating of Xcode or MacOS else.

###### Sample code for Saving image into PhotoLibrary

Sample code and error return is below. SiliconMac always returns UNKNOWN error.
Fail occurs at 'UImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum'

```
class ImageSaver: NSObject {
    func writeToPhotoAlbum(image: UIImage) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(saveCheck), nil)
    }
    @objc func saveCheck(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            print("Save NG")
        } else {
            print("Save OK")
        }
    }
}
```

###### Result of print(error):

Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-1 "Unknown error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown error, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002146490 {Error Domain=PHPhotosErrorDomain Code=3311 "(null)"}}

In the actual Error-string, "Unknown error" is "原因不明のエラー", because of my MacOS is in Japanese.

###### Confirmation

Anyway, this code works fine on iPhone, iPad, and it used to work on SiliconMac. For some reason, I am getting the error only on SiliconMac, even though there is no change in the code at all.

Already Setted Keys, Yes:

- Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
- Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description

###### Additional trials

I have tried in a different environment:
Downgraded and tried again with 14.0.1, but same result.
Update MacOS Monterey to Ventura 13.2.1, but same result.

- Other pattern-1:

  - Xcode 14.0.1
  - MacOS Monterey 12.6.2, 12.6.3  on SiliconMac, iMac24
- Other pattern-2:

  - Xcode 14.2
  - MacOS Ventura 13.2.1 on SiliconMac, iMac24

Comment: That error is [user access denied](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=3311) - Double check that your app still has photo library access.

Comment: Thank you, Paulw11, Based on your reply, I rechecked the access settings, but could not find the problem.
However, I found that it may be a different reason.
Apparently, it had something to do with the fact that I was testing with screen sharing, although I don't know why.
Only the SiliconMac was tested on a remote machine with screen sharing, but when this was tested on the actual SiliconMac, no save error occurred.
Even so, when the SiliconMac is tested remotely with screen sharing once more, an error occurs. This is reproducible. It is a strange phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

Self-Answer:
In the end, the cause seems to be different from what I imagined.
When I run the iOS app on SiliconMac as a remote machine with screen sharing, it seems to get a User Access Dinied error when saving photos.
I guess, There may have been a change in MacOS that did not give update permissions to remotely launched apps.